# Would it be appropriate to ask for a general overview of available file systems that are suitable for Linux root partitions?

Tags: discussion

I am interested in getting a general overview of available file systems for Linux (specifically to be used for the root file system), with pros and cons of each, but I am wondering would that be considered too broad a topic for this website? This is as opposed to asking about a specific file system.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks, well I asked the question, so I'm hoping you're not the only one that believes it is suitable [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371490/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-various-file-systems-available-for-root-partit) it is and it's already got a vote to close!

Comment: If you ask a question on Meta, you should wait longer than an hour to get replies. Unless you're in a hurry, at least a day or two.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. I was in a bit of a hurry, though.

Answer (score 6):

Without a very specific use case with explicit requirements mentioned, this would be a question that would be *primarily opinion based* and/or *too broad*, in my opinion.

It would be primarily opinion based, because Linux people have their favourite filesystems that they use for various reasons. Some swear by *this* filesystem, others by *another* filesystem, and sometimes on purely emotional (or other non-technical) grounds.

It would be too broad, because specific filesystems may be better for specific use cases, such as a private laptop, a server room RAID array, a high throughput genomic sequencing storage machine, a router, etc.

To alleviate these issues, the question would have to be on the form

> I tried doing *this* on *this* kind of filesystem, but *this* happened. What filesystems would better handle *this* scenario?

The question "[Filesystem for Gentoo root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35976/filesystem-for-gentoo-root)" does this. The problem is *specific*: user has performance issues on a Gentoo workstation using `ext4` when there are many small files.

Comment: And the list of filesystems changes, and their features change...